# Simple 'if' or logic statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

How would you write the following in Python?

```
if key < 1 or key > 34:
```

I've tried every way I can think of and am finding it very frustrating.

Comment: What problem do you have? Which error do you get? Your example is valid python code in my opinion!?

Comment: Are you looking for a specific syntax? The statement you wrote about _is_ how you would write it in Python.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

If `key` isn't an `int` or `float` but a `str`ing, you need to convert it to an `int` first by doing

```
key = int(key)
```

or to a `float` by doing

```
key = float(key)
```

Otherwise, what you have in your question should work, but

```
if (key < 1) or (key > 34):
```

or

```
if not (1 <= key <= 34):
```

would be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a Boolean thing:

```
if (not suffix == "flac" )  or (not suffix == "cue" ):   # WRONG! FAILS
    print  filename + ' is not a flac or cue file'
```

but

```
if not (suffix == "flac"  or suffix == "cue" ):     # CORRECT!
       print  filename + ' is not a flac or cue file'
```

`(not a) or (not b) ==  not ( a and b )` ,
is false only if a and b are both true

`not (a or b)`
is true only if a and be are both false.